# git svn clone except a particular folder

Tags: svn, git, version-control, git-svn

I want to git clone an svn repository except for one folder in the root folder of svn.

How do I do it?

I could do `git svn clone svnrepo/dir/sb-dir/` if I needed only `sb-dir` but I need all folders (and files) within the `dir` except the `design` folder

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `--ignore-paths=<regex>` option to `git svn init` or `git svn fetch`, or add the config option `svn-remote.<name>.ignore-paths` to `.git/config`.  This is documented as "This allows one to specify a Perl regular expression that will cause skipping of all matching paths from checkout from SVN."  Search the [manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) for "ignore-paths" for more details.

After trying the experiment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668752/git-svn-ignore-paths/9688205#9688205), I learned that the regex appears to be applied to the full path of each directory or file from the repository root.  Therefore, if you have a standard repository layout and want to exclude the same thing from each trunk/branch/tag, you can use a regex like `^(trunk|((branches|tags)/[^/]+))/(<file-to-ignore>|<other-file-to-ignore>)(/|$)`.

Comment: This is the only place where I have found relatively useful regex to exclude a directory in all branches. But please: add a slash between trunk/branches part and the part where you describe what to exclude. Also, add a slash at the very end of the regex.

Comment: @stgatilov Thanks for the suggestions :)  I added a slash between the branches and the files, but I didn't add a slash to the end, because the regular expression works for both folders and files this way, and none of the examples in [the documentation](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) have a trailing slash

Comment: @stgatilov Upon closer inspection, it seems that a regex like `file-a` also matches e.g. `file-abc`, which makes both my answer's regex and the regexes in the documentation unsafe.  I've added `(/|$)` to the end of the regex, which should fix this issue for both files and folders

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the [latest Git1.7.0](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/RelNotes-1.7.0.txt), it offers a **sparse checkout** feature.

> "sparse checkout" feature allows only part of the work tree to be checked out.

See [Git Sparse Checkout SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336580/sparse-checkout-in-git-1-7-0) for more: you still need to clone the *all* repo, but you can checkout (i.e. fill your working tree) with only parts of the cloned repo)

---

The only other way would to transform `design` as a submodule.
As the [GitPro book mentions](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html):

> Git's submodule support allows a repository to contain, as a subdirectory, a checkout of an external project.
>   Submodules maintain their own identity; the submodule support just stores the submodule repository location and commit ID, so other developers who clone the containing project ("superproject") can easily clone all the submodules at the same revision.
>   **Partial checkouts of the superproject are possible: you can tell Git to clone none, some or all of the submodules.**

Submodule is the only way I am aware to achieve "partial cloning", since n your case it is the cloning part which is problematic.
From your comments:

> my problem is that design folder is some 700 mb; and it takes hours to git svn clone. Whole of the rest of the project put together is in 10s of mb.

But that means modifying the SVN repo, to isolate `design` as an "external" reference, then `git svn clone` and add in the cloned Git repo a submodule reference.

Comment: Thanks! But my problem is that design folder is some 700 mb; and it takes hours to git svn clone. Whole of the rest of the project put together is in 10s of mb. It is wrong in the first place I know, to put it in repo. But I wanted some sane way to deal locally using git. Doesn;t seem possible, then

Comment: @becomingGuru: the sane way would be to split that repo and isolate design in its own repo, referenced as a submodule. That way, you would achieve *exactly* what you are looking for. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository