# Getting maven and git to work

Tags: git, maven-2, hudson, maven-release-plugin

I have recently began delving into git and maven. I have a system that has several module sets and this is stored in various git repositories, I need this to be pulled down into the same workspace and run various maven goals.

I was wondering if anyone else has run through this setup and provide tired and true way of doing this.

I would apprecaite tutorial and solution you have come up with on your bouts with maven and git.

Please and thank you.

GC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a system that has several module sets and this is stored in various git repositories, I need this to be pulled down into the same workspace (...) .

With Subversion, I would use `svn:externals` for this. So my suggestion would be to check the [SVN external in GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571232/svn-external-in-git) question here on SO.

> (...) and run various maven goals

There is nothing particular to say about Maven, as long as you get the appropriate structure out of your various Git repositories. And for the release part, just declare the relevant [GIT SCM URL](http://maven.apache.org/scm/git.html) in the [`<scm>`](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#SCM) element of the various modules.