# SVN:Externals equivalent for Git

Tags: git, svn, version-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SVN external in GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571232/svn-external-in-git)

Is there an equivalent way to include other repository locations in a Git Branch, like how SVN:Externals works?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571232/svn-external-in-git

Answer (score 0):

[Git submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) and to an extent Git subtree merge.