# How to run svn update in a loop to import commits to git?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn, revision

**Current setup**
I am running a local *git* repository in parallel to a *svn* checkout in the same folder. Whenever something new happens on the *svn* server I run `svn update` to download the commits. Then I `git add && git commit` the whole set of changes to the *git* repository.

**Task**
I want to checkout each commit separately to being able to `git add && git commit` the change with the corresponding commit message from *svn*.

**Ideas**
I already found out that I can use `svnversion` to retrieve the revision numbers of the working copy and the server.

```
// svnversion -h
usage: svnversion [OPTIONS] [WC_PATH [TRAIL_URL]]

  Produce a compact 'version number' for the working copy path
  WC_PATH.  TRAIL_URL is the trailing portion of the URL used to
  determine if WC_PATH itself is switched (detection of switches
  within WC_PATH does not rely on TRAIL_URL).  The version number
  is written to standard output.  For example:

    $ svnversion . /repos/svn/trunk
    4168

  The version number will be a single number if the working
  copy is single revision, unmodified, not switched and with
  an URL that matches the TRAIL_URL argument.  If the working
  copy is unusual the version number will be more complex:

   4123:4168     mixed revision working copy
   4168M         modified working copy
   4123S         switched working copy
   4123P         partial working copy, from a sparse checkout
   4123:4168MS   mixed revision, modified, switched working copy

   ...
```

**Note**
I would be happy to discuss ideas with you to solve the task.
A later setup would also include *svn externals* which is why I cannot checkout the *svn* repository via *git-svn*.

Answer (score 3):

There are two more options you might want to investigate:

1. [SmartGit](http://syntevo.com/smartgit/)

   SmartGit is Subversion + Git client, that means SmartGit works with local Git repository but you can add svn repository as a remote (similar to git remotes). SmartGit is much more superior than git-svn feature-wise. For more details please refer to [SmartGit vs. git-svn comparison](http://syntevo.com/git-svn/features.html).

   In particular SmartGit does support both git submodules and svn externals pretty well, so you can even mix them.

   SmartGit is proprietary software but it's free for non-commercial usage.
2. [SubGit](http://subgit.com/)

   SubGit is the server-side solution. That means you have to install SubGit and connect it to your Subversion repository that basically includes two steps:

   1. Perform initial translation of SVN repository via SubGit to freshly created Git repository.
   2. Install SubGit specific hooks which are triggered on every `git push`, so every change get synchronized between Git and SVN repositories.

For more details you may refer to [SubGit documentation](http://subgit.com/howto).

SubGit is proprietary software. SubGit is free for small teams with up to 10 committers and for academic and open-source projects.
 SubGit is also available as an add-on for the Bitbucket Server, to find out more check out [here](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.tmatesoft.subgit.stash-svn-importer/server/overview).

DISCLAIMER:
I'm SubGit developer and I work in a close contact with SmartGit developers. But these two projects seem very relevant to your particular case. Hope you'll find my comment helpful.

Comment: The [feature description of SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/git-svn/features.html?highlight=externals) sounds promissing: "Submodule-like support via bi-directional mapping of svn:externals". I'll give it a try. +1 --- Nevertheless, I would like to create a shell script.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can try `git svn` whose sole purpose is to work with SVN and Git simultaneously.

Dont use `svn` directly. Here is all you need to setup and work with SVN and Git.

http://progit.org/book/ch8-1.html

Comment: I myself never worked with svn externals but you might find what you looking for [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/571232/525978)

Comment: @havexz I am already using `git-svn` quiet a while. But this time `svn externals` are involved..

Answer (score 0):

I once created a "continous integration" like shell script which was basically an

```
while true
do
  sleep 42
  if svn up | grep '^. ' | egrep '^[ABDUCGE]*'
  # the first grep drops the "At revision xxx" line
  # the second grep searches for the update status codes
  then
    #do something
  fi
done
```

But I write this only from memory, maybe there are some other messages which `svn up` may produce`.

Comment: But this run `svn up` and retrieves all the changes at once - doesn't it?