# Howto create bzr repo which consist of many project

Tags: git, version-control, project-management, bazaar, rcs

I have big project which consist of many smaller projects, files, packages, iso's, etc. and I'd like to keep these files in some control system perhaps `Bazaar`.

The problem is some of projects are already under git or bazaar. I need not to change structure of projects/files.

Any idea, help?

Answer (score 1):

Keep each existing small projects / packages in bazaar/git.
Import other non-versioned into bazaar/git. Choose the best structure for you : each one in its own repository, or a shared repository with every thing inside.

Then, **create an new project under bazaar/git with links to each of your projects.**
This link feature is call EXTERNAL.

BAZAAR Externals
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/externals-plugin.html

GIT Externals (compared to SVN)
[SVN:externals equivalent in GIT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571232/svn-external-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options for combining repositories from different version control systems and tools that can help with that:

- [mr](http://joeyh.name/code/mr/) performs common operations on a set of repositories as if they were one
- When using bzr as the top-level repository, you can use [bzr externals](https://launchpad.net/bzr-externals) (but be aware the plugin is not very mature and unmaintained) to combine bzr and git repositories via [bzr-git](https://launchpad.net/bzr-git)
- When using git as the top-level repository you can use [submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.htm) or [subtrees](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree) to combine git and bzr repositories via a [bzr remote helper](https://felipec.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/git-remote-hg-bzr-2/)