# Check out file in multiple locations within the same repo similar to SVN externals

Tags: git, git-submodules, svn-externals, git-subtree, sparse-checkout

I've ported a SVN repo to GIT, but previously I have an svn:external file and it's not recognized in GIT. Is it possible to do external files like SVN where you have a single source of a file, but checked-out into other directories of the same repo?

For example:

```
- test/img/hello.gif (original file)
- test2/img/hello.gif (references the first file)
- test3/img/hello.gif (references the first file)
```

I've read some things around 'sparse-checkout' but not sure how you could actually just reference/check out one file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN:externals equivalent in GIT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571232/svnexternals-equivalent-in-git)

Comment: I'm within the 1 same repo, not multiple repos.

Comment: Would symlinks work for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have only one repo, you cannot use the "[submodule following a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18088319/6309)" feature.

That leaves only symlinks (I agree here with [Zach Latta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1001686/zach-latta)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060750/check-out-file-in-multiple-locations-within-the-same-repo-similar-to-svn-externa/20065172#comment29883180_20060750)), even though they are tricky to put in place when used with Windows: see "[Git Symlinks in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16754068/6309)".
A symlink isn't exactly the equivalent of an SVN:external (since it cannot reference a specific revision like svn:external can), but it can be a good enough workaround in your case.

Comment: Thanks, symlinks seems the way to go, I'll read up more on that, currently having issues with developers working on different environments, making symlinks files unreadable on windows.