# Using git with a similar layout to svn externals

Tags: git

There is a specific java utility package in a rather large java project that I would like to replicate to another project. This should be refactored into a separate dependency but that's not in the cards.

I want to replicate the the package into the new project/new repository without having to pull all of the old project's code and dependencies.

It would also be really nice if this works similar to "svn externals" as specified in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571232/svnexternals-equivalent-in-git). Ideally, devs would be able to checkout the repo, get the package from the older project, make changes, and commit without having to concern themselves with the history of the source, but it would be available for the curious.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the git way.

This sounds like fork and branch