# Git submodules as svn externals

Tags: git, svn, externals

We have set of libraries (C++ classes) in our SVN repository. I would like to move them to git, but a problem has arised. Now we incorporate classes into project as svn externals in form:
`^/classes/classdir1@1234 class1
^/classes/classdir13@81 otherclass`

and so on.

In git i can't acheive same functionality with submodules as they point to repo not subdirectory. I was thinking about splitting those classes into their own repositories but it would become a headache i think, as they sometimes inherit each another or even use "interface" classes located in another directory.

Real problem is we sometimes want version A of class X and version C of class Y and in repo those classes are in versions D and G - it's really easy to do it in SVN. How to do it in git way?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3132221/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/18088319/6309

Comment: I did (and many other) but i don't see how it would help me (i'm git newbie and maybe i miss something obvious). In svn i can point external to specific subdirectory in specific revision. Another subdirectory in other revision, and so on. Can i do this in git?

Comment: Not really, Git reasons in term of repository, not folder of files.