# How to deal with partial svn:externals when migrating to Git?

Tags: git, svn, git-subtree, svn-externals

I would like to import a SVN repository into a GitHub Enterprise repository

There are many questions related to this matter and most of them can be addressed either with Git submodules or Git subtree.

In my case I have two repositories:

- The main project repository
- The modules repository (a big SVN repository over 2 GB)

This module repository has the following architecture:

```
foolib/
   moduleA/
      ...
   moduleB/
      ...
   ...
```

For the project, only few modules from `foolib` are used as `svn:externals`. For example this main project only uses `moduleA` from `foolib`.

As mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336580/sparse-checkout-in-git-1-7-0) one possible solution is to use sparse-checkout. I'm guessing Git subtree would also do the trick. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the main issue.

If my project is very small, as long as I get something from `foolib`, even with sparce-checkout, I will retrieve the whole history of `foolib` (*e.g.* 2 GB). This issue doesn't exist with SVN because an `svn:externals` property only fetches what it needs, not the whole history.

I can imagine to do foolish things like recreating a local sparse repository dynamically using the commits listed in `git log --follow foolib/moduleA`. But I assume this is not a good solution.

What would be the correct workflow to get a similar behavior in Git without having to fetch the whole history of `foolib` everything I need only few modules?

Comment: "one possible solution": to which problem? Where is your git repo? Or are you using git-svn? I am still confused.

Comment: @VonC, I've edited my question. The main issue there is with `submodules`, `sparse-checkout` or `subtree` I will always get the whole history of `foolib` which is huge. I would like to avoid this somehow.

Comment: @VonC Any news?

Comment: Could you consider https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/ in order to isolate each module in its own repo? (once `foolib` has been imported from SVN into one giant Git repo)

Comment: This can help splitting the giant Git repo into smaller ones

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. That way, you can define a parent project with, as submodues, only the subrepos you need.