# Create a shorcut with GIT into the same repository (similar to SVN externals)

Tags: git, svn, gitlab, svn-externals

We are migrating projects from SVN to GIT.

I have an issue. 
In one of the SVN project, they used SVN externals in order to create shortcuts between modules like this :

```
-ModuleA       
|_ srcA    
-ModuleB    
|_ srcB    
-Common    
|_ srcCommon    
|_ srcA (via externals)    
|_ srcB (via externals)
```

When I do a checkout of the svn repository, in my folder Common, I have 3 files.

**Admitting that these 3 modules are in the same git repository** now (for some budget reasons...), how can I make it similar in git.
(from what I understand, subtree or submodule works when having two differents repositories)

Because for now if I clone the git repository, I have :

```
-ModuleA    
|_ srcA
-ModuleB    
|_ srcB    
-Common    
|_ srcCommon
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVN:externals equivalent in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571232/svnexternals-equivalent-in-git)

Comment: Here, the difference is that all my sources are in the same Git repository